# actionscript number is between():Boolean

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

Does Actionscript have a built-in function that accepts a number and can return a Boolean if this number is between 2 numbers.

For example

```
3 is between 2 and 6   //returns true
5 is between 10 and 20 //returns false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you can easily code one yourself:

```
public static function isBetween(x : Number, low: Number, high : Number) : Boolean {
    return ((x>=low)&&(x<=high));
}
```

So, for your example, isBetween(3,2,6) returns true and isBetween(5,10,20) returns false. That said, simply using the boolean expression ((x>=2)&&(x<=6)) is much more readable than isBetween(x,2,6).

Comment: +1, "simply using the boolean expression is much more readable"

Answer (score 0):

function calls are pretty slow, so I would stay away from this if you can at all avoid it.

It's not that hard to write: if (x > low && x < high)